# Performance difference between Insert and Insert Where Not Exists

Tags: sql, oracle, query-optimization, sql-insert

I know its better to use INSERT WHERE NOT EXISTS than INSERT as it leads to duplicated records or unique key violation issues.
But with respect to performance, will it create any big difference ?

INSERT WHERE NOT EXISTS will internally triggers extra SELECT statement to check the record is existing or not. In case of large tables, which is recommended to use INSERT vs INSERT WHERE NOT EXITS ? 
And someone pls explain cost of execution difference between the both.

Comment: Performance mainly depends on how many rows you are inserting at a time. If you are inserting BULK records, of course there are performance issue but if you are inserting a single row, that's not a big deal. Now, if you go for using IF EXISTS, please try to apply Index on the column you are using in Where clause.

Comment: Comparing data integrity with performance is a false dichotomy. You can't corrupt your database just because it's quicker to load rubbish.

Answer (score 0):

Most Oracle IN clause queries involve a series of literal values, and when a table is present a standard join is better. In most cases the Oracle cost-based optimizer will create an identical execution plan for IN vs EXISTS, so there is no difference in query performance.

The Exists keyword evaluates true or false, but the IN keyword will compare all values in the corresponding subquery column.  If you are using the IN operator, the SQL engine will scan all records fetched from the inner query. On the other hand, if we are using EXISTS, the SQL engine will stop the scanning process as soon as it found a match.

The EXISTS subquery is used when we want to display all rows where we have a matching column in both tables.  In most cases, this type of subquery can be re-written with a standard join to improve performance.

The EXISTS clause is much faster than IN when the subquery results is very large. Conversely, the IN clause is faster than EXISTS when the subquery results is very small.

Also, the IN clause can't compare anything with NULL values, but the EXISTS clause can compare everything with NULLs.

Comment: Do you have any reference that "EXISTS is much faster than IN" for Oracle?  I think Oracle has a good optimizer and would expect the performance to be comparable (although I personally do prefer EXISTS).

Comment: @GordonLinoff - at least in Oracle, the optimizer implements IN and EXISTS differently. Consequently there are performance benefits to choosing the appropriate operation when there is a meaningful difference in the relative sizes of the main query and the subquery. [Find out more](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:953229842074).

Comment: @APC I'm sure there are cases where IN and EXISTS are treated differently but usually I find that they get the same plan. NOT IN and NOT EXISTS are two different things, though.

Comment: @APC . . . The issue is not whether they are executed in the same manner.  The issue is whether you can say that one is always much better than the other.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - neither Black Swan nor Tom Kyte in the article linked to says one is **always** better. Rather it depends. You asked for a reference and I provided one. Although I agree that improvements to the optimizer and machine power over the years make it harder to find cases where the difference matters.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a matter of "what's fastest" but a matter of "what's correct".

When you `INSERT` into a table (without any restriction) you simply add records to that table. If an existing identical record already was in there this will then result there now being two such records. This may be fine or this may be an issue depending on your needs (**).

When you add a `WHERE NOT EXISTS()` to your `INSERT` construction the system will only add records to the table that aren't there yet, thus avoiding the situation of ending up with multiple identical records.

(**: suppose you have unique or primary key constraint on the target table then the `INSERT` of a duplicate record will result in a UQ/PK Violation error. *IF* your question was: "What's fastest: try to insert the row and if there is such an error simply ignore it versus try to insert where not exists() and avoid the error" then I can't give you conclusive answer but I'm fairly certain it will be a close call. What I can say however is that the WHERE NOT EXISTS() approach will look much nicer in code and *(importantly!)* it will also work for set-based operations, the try/catch approach will fail for the entire set even if only 1 record causes an issue.)

Answer (score 0):

INSERT will check inserted data against any existing schema constraints, PK, FK, Unique Indexes, not nulls and any other custom constraints - whatever the table schema demands. If those checks are ok, the row will be inserted and loop on to the next row.

INSERT WHERE NOT EXISTS, prior to the above check, will check data of all columns of the row against data of all rows of the table. Even if 1 column is different it is ok and then it will move on exactly as INSERT above.

The performance impact mostly depends:
1. number of existing rows at the table
2. size of row

So as the table gets larger followed by larger row size the difference grows.